# Скрипт берет ссылку из текста и вставляет ее в то место, которое отмечено

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как реализовать скрипт, чтоб находил в тексте фразу Источник, брал оттуда данные в виде `HTTP://` и вставлял в определенное поле. Таких скриптов может быть много.

Comment: Регулярные выражения тут в самый раз

Comment: @kpik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = /источник:\s*([^\s]+)/i,
    str = "текст...\r\nисточник: http://site.com/index.php?foo=15\r\nпродолжение текста";

console.log(pattern.exec(str));
```

или [демонстрация на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs1n8fxL/)